# Insertar imagen con CSS3 en una extensión de Chrome

Tags: css3, google-chrome, extensiones

Estoy haciendo una extensión de Chrome con HTML, CSS3 y JS. El problema es que la imagen de fondo de un `div` no aparece.

La imagen icono.png esta en la carpeta raíz de la extensión y en mi código CSS3 la llamo con background: url("/icono.png"). Al parecer la ruta de la imagen es incorrecta, entonces, ¿cuál seria la ruta correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre darle una solucion al problema que tenia. En vez de hacer el Backgroud con `Background: url("icono.png")` inserte la imagen codificada en base 64 y se soluciono el problema.

Comment: https://tonalidad.es/blog/convertir-imagen-base64/ Este articulo me ayudo